# How do you un-deploy Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was experimenting with Cloud Functions for Firebase and deployed one of the samples in the [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) and linked it to an existing project using `firebase use --add`.

Since I was just playing around, these files were not added to my version control, and I no longer have access to the machine this was done on. I would like to build on this function or create new ones, but I am unsure how to either 1) modify and re-deploy over the original function or 2) un-`use --add` and start fresh. I see the function in my firebase console but no 'delete' or 'remove' button and have read through the CLI docs looking for clues to no avail.

Thanks for adding functions to the firebase 'stack.' Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Functions get deleted when they aren't present during a `firebase deploy`. Most commonly that'd be because because you removed the function from your `index.js`, but if you've removed the whole `functions` directory that'll work too.

To continue work on a function for which you don't have the source anymore, the easiest is to start fresh. The function(s) you deploy will replace the ones you deployed previously.

Alternatively, if you're partial to using the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) instead of the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), the Cloud Console will show you the code for the currently-deployed function, so you can copy-paste it onto your local machine.

The Cloud Console also has a 'delete' button for every function, and even a web editor. Be aware when editing functions from the Cloud Console though: your next `firebase deploy` will overwrite any changes.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if you're a firebaser, but if any are listening, I'd recommend specifying in the CLI or functions docs that firebase is looking for a `functions` directory in the directory where you run `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Yup, Firebaser here. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll take it up with the authors of the docs! :)

Comment: Hello, I want delete the functions permanently, Any help? I couldn't find the buttons or options of delete.

Comment: Removing the functions from your `functions/index.js` and running `firebase deploy` should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be nice to have a something like `firebase undeploy --only functions`

Comment: View the detailed log **Google Cloud Platform** have options like **Edit**,**Delete**.

Comment: Thanks! I had accidentally overwrote index.js with a remote version that hadn't been saved, I was able to retrieve the deployed source from the Google Cloud Console!

Answer (score 49):

To delete a function explicitly use the following command:

**`$ firebase functions:delete myFunction`**

Replace *myFunction* with your function name. For detailed info. follow this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

Comment: note you need the latest firebase-tools to do this. Currently `4.1.1`. My problem was that `3.x` did not have the delete.

Answer (score 45):

Go to [Google Cloud Console Cloud Functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/) and select project, then select the function you want to undeploy or delete. Select it and click delete.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To delete/undeploy a single function, you can delete the code for your function and then run the following in command line:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:YourFunctionName
```

---

*Replace `YourFunctionName` with the name of your function*

In the case that you are working on other functions that you are not ready to deploy or do not want to deploy all of your functions for any reason, then the code above can be handy.  This also feels a bit safer since you're not redeploying everything :)

Comment: You most probably would need to specify --force option https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/commands/deploy.js#L44

Comment: If you don't add `--force`, it will ask you if you are sure you want to delete the function.  If you add `--force`, it won't ask.  I prefer to have it ask me, but a good point that you can add `--force` if you prefer it not to!

Comment: that makes sense to me in non-interactive mode

Answer (score 4):

Now you can simply delete a function from the function dashboard as follows. Click on the three dots mark of relevant function in the right side corner.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that 'delete function' no longer available. we need to choose 'Detailed usage stats' instead, then it will bring you to https://console.cloud.google.com/ , then delete the function from the console

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make it happen.

The method is to go into https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/
=> TRANSFER DATA => Transfer data in

Then you Create a transfer job

1. Source/Destination type = Google Cloud Storage
2. Select Source as gcf-source-[project number]-[region]
3. Select Destination as [project name].appspot.com => Create new folder as FunctionCode
4. Run job immediate
5. Wait until complete

Then visit your firebase storage in folder FunctionCode

Bingo!! You get your source code of your previous released. Use it to redeploy again as you wish.

Note: In my understanding, google will help to keep latest 2 versions for us in gcf-source-[project number]-[region].